# tradingview lightweight-charts time axis strange behaviour

Tags: tradingview-api, lightweight-charts

I need to display this chart:

```
var chart = LightweightCharts.createChart(document.body, {
  width: 600,
  height: 300
});
chart.applyOptions({
  timezone: "Europe/Paris",
  timeScale: {
    timeVisible: true,
    secondsVisible: true,
  },
  localization: {
    locale: 'it',
  },
});
var areaSeries = chart.addAreaSeries({
  topColor: 'rgba(21, 146, 230, 0.4)',
  bottomColor: 'rgba(21, 146, 230, 0)',
  lineColor: 'rgba(21, 146, 230, 1)',
  lineStyle: 0,
  lineWidth: 3,
  crosshairMarkerVisible: false,
  crosshairMarkerRadius: 3,
});

areaSeries.setData([{
  "time": 905299200,
  "value": 0.25
}, {
  "time": 918781200,
  "value": 0.0
}, {
  "time": 935952000,
}, {
  "time": 965952000,
  "value": 0.25
}, {
  "time": 983408400,
  "value": 0.15
}, {
  "time": 985050000,
  "value": 0.0
}, {
  "time": 1152835200,
  "value": 0.25
}, {
  "time": 1172019600,
  "value": 0.5
}, {
  "time": 1225414800,
  "value": 0.3
}, {
  "time": 1229648400,
  "value": 0.1
}, {
  "time": 1286236800,
  "value": 0.1
}, {
  "time": 1454029200,
  "value": -0.1
}, {
  "time": 1454288400,
  "value": 0.0
}]);
```

but if you look at the time axis at 2000-2006 and 2006-2008, space used is more or less the same so the chart look strange, how can I fix this issue without any change to the json?

I've found a solution adding some points without value field like this: { "time" : valueBetweenTwoPoints}
but this could maybe deal to some errors.

Answer (score 1):

The `lightweight-chart` does know nothing about your data and what period they should have. If you'd like to have "smooth" time scale, you need to fill the gaps to make it in the way that distance between any 2 points are the same for all data points.

Currently you can "fill the gaps" with data points only (even if it'll be other series), but [we're going to add ability to provide "whitespaces"](https://github.com/tradingview/lightweight-charts/issues/209), so after that you'll be able to provide "empty" data points to the series and we'll "align" the time scale in that way.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to justify data with such function:

```js
    export function justifyData(data, span = 15 * 60) {
      var justifiedData = [], lastTime
      data.each(item => {
        var {time} = item
        while (lastTime && lastTime + span * 1.4 < time) {
          lastTime += span
          justifiedData.push({time: lastTime})
        }
        justifiedData.push(item)
        lastTime = time
      })
      return justifiedData
    }

    yourSeries.setData(justifyData(data))
```